Как внедрить Redis в бота Aiogram?
Пишу бота на aiogram. Возникла необходимость использовать Redis хранилище, но так как aiogram - библиотека асинхронная, то говорят, надо использовать aioredis.
Но я пишу код на Python 3.12, а еще в Python 3.11, как известно, asyncio.TimeoutError сделано псевдонимом builtins.TimeoutError, и поэтому библиотека не работает.
Откатываться на 3.10 после того, как половина бота написана - не хочется…
Как же сейчас понимаю, что со стеком надо было определиться заранее… короче, что делать? Что посоветуете?
Redis мне был нужен для того, чтобы реализовать ttl. Пользователь проходит тест и ответы запоминаются на 3 месяца. Лишь по прохождении этого периода времени он сможет пройти тест снова. Посчитал, что для этой цели Redis оочень к месту.
Что можно использовать вместо Redis и как вообще выйти из этой ситуации?

Так официальная библиотека redis на Python поддерживает же асинхронность из "коробки".
